# Reading /proc/PID/maps of short-lived process

Tags: linux, memory, debian, proc, aslr

I have a binary that exits/segfaults shortly after executing. I am trying to read /proc/PID/maps of this binary before it exits but with no luck.

I've tried `cat /proc/($./binary [input] & echo $!)/maps` which should result in /proc/pidofprocess/maps but always get No such file or directory.

My goal is to see where things get loaded to on subsequent runs.

Comment: You should be using `gdb` for this.

Comment: how can gdb give me this output? Also with gdb would memory randomization not be turned off? Ie wouldn't it load in the same place always?

Comment: @iControlEIP if you run it from gdb it would be *stopped* on SIGSEGV, and then you could read its `/proc/PID/maps` in any way you see fit ;-)

Comment: @IControlEIP: gdb memory randomization is [configurable](http://visualgdb.com/gdbreference/commands/set_disable-randomization)

Comment: `(gdb) info proc mapping` will give you this if you really need it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You solution `cat /proc/$(<pipeline>)/maps` won't call `cat` until the whole `<pipeline>` has ended (even if you use `&` within it), so you will never get your `maps`.

On the other hand,

```
<pipeline> & cat /proc/${!}/maps
```

will return immediately. Of course, as your binary exits immediately, `cat` may still run too late to capture  `/proc/${!}/maps`

But you could try:

```
while true; do; ./binary [input] & cat /proc/${!}/maps ; done
```

This restarts a race between your `binary` and `cat` all day long, and *sometimes* `cat` may win (it does, in my case, with `ls <nonexisting file>` instead of `./binary` 1 out of 30 times)

This prints a lot of garbage on your terminal, but you can collect the succesful maps by redirecting your `cat`s output:

```
while true; do; ./binary [input] & cat /proc/${!}/maps >> mymaps; done
```

Elegant? No. Effective: I hope so!